# Add XML element before last element using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to add new element before the last element of the XML using Linq.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <product id="p1">
    <name>Delta</name>
    <price>800</price>
    <country>Denmark</country>
  </product>
  <product id="p3">
    <name>Alfa</name>
    <price>1200</price>
    <country>Germany</country>
  </product>
</products>
```

New element `<stock></stock>` should be inserted before `<country>` element using Linq

Comment: Okay, so you just add a new XElement to the root, and it will be put at the end automatically. What have you tried so far, and what went wrong? And are you using LINQ or not? (Your title and body disagree...) And by LINQ to you mean "LINQ to XML" or "LINQ queries"?

Comment: Using Linq? Without using Linq? Which is it? And by "last element" are you referring to the last `product` element?

Answer (score 0):

```
// load the XML file into XDocument instance
var doc = XDocument.Load("sourceFile.xml");

// find all <country> elements
var countries = doc.Root.Elements("product").Elements("Country");

// add <stock /> before each <country> elements
foreach(var country in countries)
{
    country.AddBeforeSelf(new XElement("stock"));
}

// save document to the file
doc.Save("sourceFile.xml");
```

Comment: I used following statement to add element xdoc.Elements("Products").Descendants("product").ToList ().ForEach (el=>el.LastNode.AddBeforeSelf (new XElement ("stock")));  In above query I used foreach statement.
Is there any way to add without using to use any looping?